# Can I try to ping a website through a specific adapter?

Tags: windows, networking, vbscript, wmi

I hope this isn't too basic a question.  The title kind of asks it all.  :-)

Comment: The title doesn't say whether you want a command to do this, or whether you want to write a program to do this. It also doesn't say what language or platform you're talking about.

Comment: ping -I (wlan0,eth0..) www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @john - this is windows.  I can use command scripting or VB Script. Thanks!

Comment: @Anders that answer applies to Unix based systems. Though it will definitely be useful for others, since this question is pretty high up in search results.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The ping command will allow strict source routing so you can specify the default gateway to use on the way out. (This assumes your interfaces have distinct gateways i.e. are on different networks)

```
ping -k 192.169.1.1 microsoft.com
        ^ default gateway for desired interface
```

Using WMI [**Win32_PingStatus**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394350(VS.85).aspx) you can do the same thing where you specify **SourceRoute** and **SourceRouteType** (This is essentially the same as using ping -k)

Alternatively:

If your network interfaces are on the same network, like a LAN card and a wireless adapater
you can add a custom **ROUTE** to your machine, which can send all traffic through a specific interface.

From **ROUTE HELP:**

```
route ADD 207.46.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0  192.168.1.1 METRIC 3 IF 2
        destination^      ^mask        ^gateway     metric^    ^
                                                      Interface^
```

Answer (score 35):

`ping` also has an option in Windows:

```
-S srcaddr     Source address to use.
```

So you can do something like

```
ping 10.10.10.1 -l 0 -S 192.168.1.1
```

where 10.10.10.1 is the destination address and 192.168.1.1 is the address of the source adapter

Comment: Does this not just change the source address?  How are we sure this is coming out of the interface that has the same source address?

Comment: @Dylan You can see that the selected interface is being used by setting that interface to use a nonexistent gateway and seeing the ping fail. Change it to a valid one and it succeeds. ABA.

Comment: And when you don't put the option *after* the address you want to ping, you get "General error"...